# CreateProcess on top of other windows applications MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, labview

I'm developing the MFC Application (C++)
On i want to open the Labview program inside the MFC application and run top of the other windows on the main application.
So, it does not work on `CreateProcess()` function.

```
#define  DIR_TEMP_MONITER   ".\\Application.exe"

STARTUPINFO         stStartup = { NULL, };
PROCESS_INFORMATION     stProcess = { NULL, };

stStartup.cb            = sizeof( STARTUPINFO );// The size of the structure
stStartup.lpReserved            = NULL;         // Reserved
stStartup.lpDesktop     = NULL;         // For NT
stStartup.lpTitle       = NULL;         // Console app title
stStartup.dwFlags       = 0;            // Which member is valid
stStartup.cbReserved2   = 0;
stStartup.lpReserved2   = NULL;


::CreateProcess(DIR_TEMP_MONITER,       // The name of the executable module
        NULL,               // Command line string
        NULL,               // Security descriptor
        NULL,               // Security descriptor
        FALSE,              // Handle inheritance option
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,      // High priority class
        NULL,               // New environment block
        NULL,               // Current directory name
        &stStartup,         // Startup information
        &stProcess );           // Process information
```

I want to make this executable program run on top of the other windows. Is there any other method to do that?

Comment: What does [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) *return*?  If it fails, what error code does [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) give you?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is that specific to LabView? Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: CreateProcess function works fine. But it open the executable file  and run the app. in my application there have many other windows open after that window. but i need to run this process on top of other windows

Comment: Laview program it is display always the Temperature sensor values

Comment: No need to fumble with creating processes or reparenting windows. LabVIEW offers [ActiveX](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvconcepts/using_activex_with_labview.html) controls specifically for the purpose of hosting LabVIEW in an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Labview program to Always on top the all application then it open in the windows CreateProcess function.
That gives always on top of the other windows applications.

thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to use

[SetWindowPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=msvc-170#setwindowpos)

In your main frame, you can write:

```
void CMainFrame::OnViewAlwaysontop() 
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here

    SetWindowPos(&wndTopMost, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

Comment: You've linked to an API that expects 7 arguments, but the code you've shown only passes 6. That's just a convenient way of dodging the hard question: How do you get the `HWND` you want to call this API for?

Comment: SetWindowPosition fn it Cannot open the executables out side the application. but it is good for the widows created inside the VC++ application.